# Rails 6 and selectize

Tags: ruby-on-rails-6, selectize.js

I am following allong the integration of selectize in an existing rails 6 app, following the guide in: https://gorails.com/episodes/select-or-create-with-selectize-js

Does not work with rails 6, after finding someone sugestion to integrate on https://gorails.com/forum/how-do-i-use-selectize-in-rails-6 i got stuck in "selectize is not a function"

Anyone who could point some directions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post some of the code that you have written or things that you have done so far?

Answer (score 0):

Add `selectize` to your packages:

```
yarn add selectize
```

Add this line to your `javascript/packs/application.js`

```
require("selectize")
```

Add the code necessary to initialize the jQuery plugin (you could also add this to your `application.js` file if you wanted to):

```
$(document).on("turbolinks:load", function() {
  $(".selectize").selectize()
})
```

Make sure your `<select>` has the matching `selectize` class that you just defined.

To import the selectize styles, add these lines to your webpack stylesheet:

```
@import "~selectize/dist/css/selectize";
@import "~selectize/dist/css/selectize.default";
```